# position fixed div, when scrolling up and position absolute, when scrolling down: google now search bar type behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to create a div behavior very similar to google now's search bar control.

When the page loads initially, you get a div located in a specific position, as you start scrolling down the div will remain in its relative/absolute position(slide along with the scroll until it disappears). Once you start scrolling up (or page up) the div would slide in from the top(along with the content) until it reaches its fixed position and stay there.

Now Ive come up with a very crude/ugly example of what Im trying to achieve and it sort of works, but Im sure there's a far better approach in general to this.

http://jsfiddle.net/9654gd6c/3/

```
var lastScrollTop = 0,
    scrH = 40,
    marginTop = 40,
    ch = {};
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    var elements = $('#scroller');

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        elements.css({
            'position': 'absolute'
        });
        ch.dir = 'down';

    } else {

        if (ch.dir === 'down') ch.at = lastScrollTop;
        if (ch.at - st - marginTop > scrH) {
            elements.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': st + marginTop
            });
        } else {
            elements.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': ch.at - scrH
            });
        }
        ch.dir = 'up';

    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

oh and the remove style button should act as immediate show div button, that brings back the div to its fixed place. Thanks for your help in advance

**Update 2**: Thanks to David Karam here's an example without switching the position
http://jsfiddle.net/rmx50du5/2/

Comment: Is this for a mobile site? In mobile it would make sense as real-estate is valuable and you don't want the bar to float with the down scroll but still help the user get it on up scroll. A few notes on the UX motivation would help provide a better solution for your problem.

Comment: well its going to be the filters section + report header row of a report page. And yes it does have a mobile version but behaviour should be the same. So the idea is when a user scrolls down he's looking for something and once he/she starts going back up perhaps he would like to change search criteria, that's why I would like to show him/her the filters.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest downside to your implementation is the fact that you are switching between position fixed and absolute. This means you cannot make use of CSS animations which can come real handy in your example.

Here's a modified version with position relative allowing for use of transitions (I use opacity but you probably want to transition on top which will require a couple of extra lines to offset the scrolling)

http://jsfiddle.net/o16bebtu/

It is a neater way of achieving what you want by making the position relative and then making use of getBoundingClientRect which accounts for scrolling position.

```
var nodeScrollTop= ((Math.ceil(rect.top))|0);
var nodeTop= (!!(_node.style.top)) ? parseInt(_node.style.top) : 0;
var newNodeTop= nodeTop - nodeScrollTop;
```

From MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

> The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or
>   any other scrollable element) is taken into account when computing the
>   bounding rectangle. This means that the top and left property change
>   their values as soon as the scrolling position changes (so their
>   values are relative to the viewport and not absolute). If this is not
>   the desired behaviour just add the current scrolling position to the
>   top and left property (via window.scrollX and window.scrollY) to get
>   constant values independent from the current scrolling position.

Comment: Thanks for the effort it is appreciated. Unfortunately using transitions I cannot achieve exactly what I want, which is for the bar to "slide down"(when scrolling up) along with the content, using the same speed/rate of scrolling as the user. or can I?

Comment: @tsonev there is no need to match the user's scrolling speed. What you can do is perform the transition only once and then at the end of it switch the node to a class that does not have the CSS transition. You can hook to the end of the transition using standard browser events.

You will need to tweak what I linked to you to make it work. The most important aspect of the answer is weaning the technique off toggling the position because that's the thing that stands in the way of achieving any smooth effect.

Comment: Im afraid I cannot understand what you are trying to say. See my updated example above, perhaps this will demonstrate better what Im trying to achieve. I dont want smooth effect for transitioning I want the bar to appear as the user scrolls, relative to the scrolling position, exactly the way the search bar behaves in Google Now.

Comment: OK I think I finally got it and thanks to your example I came up with the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28nydrjs/2/